# Do stuff before WebDeploy temporary package gets deployed

Tags: asp.net, .net, deployment, msbuild, webdeploy

I need to perform some actions on the WebDeploy temporary compiled ASP.NET application, just before it gets deployed to the target server (this way I should be able to change some files in the temporary directory without affecting development code), and the whole actions should be executed in the build machine.

Is there any MSBuild target that can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found two useful MSBuild targets so far:

- `_CopyWebApplication`. It's executed when WebDeploy copies all Web application files to compile it using ASP.NET compiler. If you want to do something against Web application files before or after they get copies to the temporary location also before WebDeploy deploys files to the destination server, this is a good moment to do stuff. For example:

```
<Target Name="YourTarget" BeforeTargets="_CopyWebApplication">
    <!-- Do stuff -->
</Target>
```

- If you declare a property group which declares a property called `BeforeAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest` and its value is a MSBuild target name, you'll be able to do stuff when the Web application has been already compiled and before it's going to be deployed to the destination server. For example:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
     <BeforeAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>MyTarget</BeforeAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="MyTarget">
      <!-- Do stuff -->
  </Target>
```